# Matching two strings and extracting the matched character in R

Tags: r, string

Consider I have the below mentioned input character;

```
text_input <- c("ADOPT", "A", "FAIL", "FAST")
test <- c("TEST", "INPUT", "FAIL", "FAST")
```

I would like to match both the inputs and extract the words which occurred in common in text_input, I would like to something similar to `str_extract`.

I do understand that `str_extract` uses a matching pattern or word to do it, but,my test data consists of around 500,000 words. Any inputs would be really helpful.

Expected Outcome:

```
"FAIL", "FAST"
```

**EDIT**

Just adding one more question here... What happens when the Input is a pure string, like, the one provided below;

```
text_input <- c("‘Data Scientist’ has been named the sexiest job of the 21st century by Harvard Business Review. The same article tells us that “demand has raced ahead of supply” and that the lack of data scientists “is becoming a serious constraint in some sectors.” A 2011 study by McKinsey Global Institute found that “there will be a shortage of talent necessary for organizations to take advantage of big data” – a shortage to the tune of 140,000 to 190,000 in the United States alone by 2018.")

test <- c("Data Scientist", "McKinsey", "ORGANIZATIONS", "FAST")
```

Is it possible to perform string match even in this case, as mentioned above.

Note: Changed the input and testing string.

Comment: What is your expected output ? Is `text_input` and `test` of same length ?

Comment: `?intersect` maybe?

Comment: so `intersect(text_input, test)` it is.

Comment: `test` is not of same length, it consists of 5L records

Comment: What is the expected output for the EDIT

Comment: The expected output for the EDIT is `Data Scientist, McKinsey, organizations`

Comment: As the above is present in the text_input, even if it's partial match, say like 50% match, then it should return the output.

Answer (score 1):

If we need the characters to be extracted

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(text_input, paste0("[", test, "]+"))
```

---

If we are looking for full string match

```
library(data.table)
fintersect(data.table(col1 = text_input), data.table(col1 = test))
```

Comment: Error Shown: 'In a character range [x-y], x is greater than y. (U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE)'

Comment: I made an edit to the question, is it possible to perform the same using the `intersect` function.

Comment: @JBH I find `thelatemail's comment below your question

Comment: @JBH DO you need `str_extract_all(text_input, paste(test, collapse="|"))`

Answer (score 1):

For the easy example you may use `intersect()` as already was stated in the comments.

```
text_input1 <- c("ADOPT", "A", "FAIL", "FAST")
test1 <- c("TEST", "INPUT", "FAIL", "FAST")
intersect(text_input1, test1)
# [1] "FAIL" "FAST"
```

The long example is a little more complicated.

```
text_input2 <- c("‘Data Scientist’ has been named the sexiest job of the 21st century by Harvard Business Review. The same article tells us that “demand has raced ahead of supply” and that the lack of data scientists “is becoming a serious constraint in some sectors.” A 2011 study by McKinsey Global Institute found that “there will be a shortage of talent necessary for organizations to take advantage of big data” – a shortage to the tune of 140,000 to 190,000 in the United States alone by 2018.")

phrases <- c("Data Scientist", "McKinsey", "ORGANIZATIONS", "FAST")
```

The test string vector you've defined - I'll call it `phrases` contains compound terms of two (or probably more) words i.e. containing spaces. Therefore, we need a regular expression `rx1` that can handle it. It is not clear if you want case sensitive matches or not, you'd need `tolower()` both the phrases and the text for the latter. Next we test whether there's a match or not. If so we extend the regex to `rx2` so that we can use it well with `gsub()` replacement functionality. We `Vectorize()` our function that it can handle vectors of phrases.

```
matchPhrase <- Vectorize(function(phr, txt, tol=FALSE) {
  rx1 <- gsub(" ", "\\\\s", phr)         # handle spaces
  if (tol) {                             # optional tolower
    rx1 <- tolower(rx1)
    txt <- tolower(txt)
  }
  if (regexpr(rx1, txt) > 0) {    # test for matches
    rx2 <- paste0(".*(", rx1, ").*") 
    return(gsub(rx2, "\\1", txt))        # gsub extraction
    } else {
      return(NA)                         # we want NA for no matches
      }
})
```

Default without case-sensitivity.

```
matchPhrase(phrases, text_input2, tol=FALSE)
#   Data Scientist         McKinsey    ORGANIZATIONS             FAST 
# "Data Scientist"       "McKinsey"               NA               NA
```

Non-case-sensitive also finds `"organizations"`.

```
matchPhrase(phrases, text_input2, tol=TRUE)
#   Data Scientist         McKinsey    ORGANIZATIONS             FAST 
# "data scientist"       "mckinsey"  "organizations"               NA
```

For a clean output just do:

```
as.character(na.omit(matchPhrase(phrases, text_input2, tol=TRUE)))
# [1] "data scientist" "mckinsey"       "organizations"
```

**Note:** Probably you need to adapt the function several times for your specific needs/desired outputs. Actually the [`quanteda`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda/index.html) package is quite sophisticated in doing this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but, for example, when there is a phrase called as 'ABOUT SERVICE PVT LTD', I am getting a output which matches only ABOUT from my text_input. Also, what does the '0' mean in (regexpr(rx1, txt) > 0).

Comment: @JBH I can't reproduce this, but when you try `phrases <- c("Data Scientist", "McKinsey", "ORGANIZATIONS", "FAST", "MCKINSEY GLOBAL INSTITUTE")` it works. The `regexpr(.)` counts the matches, and we are interested if the result is greater than zero; else the following `gsub(.)` would throw the whole text if tehre are no matches found.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using the package `fuzzyjoin`, which contains a way to join df's based on regex.

```
text_input <- c("ADOPT", "A", "FAIL", "FAST")
regex <- c("TEST", "INPUT", "FAIL", "FAST")

library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble( text = text_input )
df.regex <- tibble( regex_name = regex )

# now we can regex match them
df %>%
  regex_left_join( df.regex, by = c( text = "regex_name" ) )

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
# text  regex_name
#   <chr> <chr>     
# 1 ADOPT NA        
# 2 A     NA        
# 3 FAIL  FAIL      
# 4 FAST  FAST 

#or only regex 'hits'
df %>%
  regex_inner_join( df.regex, by = c( text = "regex_name" ) )

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# text  regex_name
#   <chr> <chr>     
# 1 FAIL  FAIL      
# 2 FAST  FAST
```